# Trying to prove T1(n)/T2(n) = O(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

If T1(n) = n^2 and T2(n) = n,

then both T1(n) and T2(n) are O(n^2).

So T1(n)/T2(n) = (n^2)/n = n.

Does T1(n)/T2(n) =  O(n) now?

I'm not sure if I'm doing this write. So my reasoning is as follows:

If I divide two algorithms T1(n)/T2(n) where T1 has n^2 time-units and T2 has n time-units, then does that make its time complexity of the division of both algorithms to be O(n)? If I'm completely off or a bit off please correct me. Thanks :]

Comment: what you mean by dividing the two algorithms?

Comment: This question is coming from a data structures and algorithms book; this is a typical algorithms question, I don't see why this can't be answered here.

Comment: @alfasin, I disagree. calculating the complexity of computer algorithms is definitely related to programming.

Comment: @HadiHassan from my understanding, doesn't T1 and T2 represent the literal runtime of two separate pieces of code (or two algorithms)?

Comment: @Ghost_Stark, I'm having a hard time imagining what T1(n)/T2(n) means.  Are you sure it's not T1(n)/T2(m)?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. I'm assuming that by `T1(n) = n^2`, you mean the function `T1(n)` is in `O(n^2)`. But you say `T2(n)` is in `O(n^2)` but also `O(n)`? And what would dividing them mean?

Comment: @ikegami this problem is coming straight from Mark Allen Weiss' algorithms book in chapter 2 question 2.2 It shows T1(n)/T2(n) = O(1). I'm trying to disprove it and show the actual solution with my explicit values.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two, It does make sense. O() is an upper bound, so something O(N) is also O(N^2). He picked a less precise bound to simplify the math, but the end result would be the same if he hadn't.

Comment: @Ghost_Stark what I know about algorithms is that you can divide an algorithm into small pieces of code ( functions), you can run algorithms in parallel to gain time, but how you will divide algorithm T1 for example to paint and T2 to count up to 100000 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that T1(n) = n^2 and T2(n) = n then you can just do the division and find that T1(n) / T2(n) = n as you have done.

If you are just told that T1(n) is O(n^2) and T2(n) is O(n) then you have to remember that O() notation is an upper bound. If T2(n) = 1 when n is prime and n when n is not prime then T2(n) is O(n), but if T1(n) = n^2 then T1(n)/T2(n) is n^2 when n is prime and n when n is not prime, so T1(n)/T2(n) is O(n^2) and is not O(n)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. So we were able to show that T1(n)/T2(n) = n. My question now is how do I translate that value (n) into Big-Oh notation? I understand how to do it if T1(n) + T2(n) = n^2 + n = O(n^2) and T1(n) - T2(n) = n^2 - n = O(n^2). I'm just stuck when it comes to dividing.

Comment: To provide an upper bound for T1(n)/T2(n), you need to provide an upper bound for T1(n) but a lower bound for T2(n) --provided that both quantities are positive. If T1(n) is O(n^2), you know that an upper bound is a polynomial of degree 2, so fine. If T2(n) is O(n), the only lower bound you have is 1 (i.e. constant time). So the ratio T1(n)/T2(n) is O(n^2). For a concrete example, think about T1(n)=n^2 and T2(n) = 1 = O(n).